# How to implement PayPal Donate button behavior with PayPal REST API?

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I'm developing a .NET (C#) volunteer/donor web application. I tried to use the JavaScript PayPal Donate button, but couldn't get it to show up in jQueryUI dialog. So now I am using the REST API
to accept donations. The transaction seems to work fine, but, when the user gets redirected to
the PayPal screen (approval_url), it looks like the interface for a purchase with shipping address (express checkout).

The approval_url looks like this:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

How can I implement the REST API to display the "Donate quickly with PayPal" screen that users get when using the JavaScript PayPal Donate button?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up using "PAYPAL.apps.ButtonFactory.create(PayPalButtonMerchantAccount, PayPalButtonData, "donate")" to dynamically create the PayPal donate button (only way I could get them to show up in my div) and Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to capture transaction details.